# CSS selector is not finding element in selenium grid

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find Submit element. My HTML structure is as below.

```html
<div> 
  <span class="combutton"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Submit</a></span>
</div> 
<div> 
 <span class="combutton"><a href="#Cancel">Cancel</a></span>
</div>
```

In browser using firebug I tried

```
$('div .combutton')[0].click()
```

which clicks on submit perfectly. But using selenium driver this element is not found. Please tell me how to do this using

```
driver.findElement(By.css("CSSSELECTORSTRING"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did in Firebug shouldn't have any effect since it's clicking on a `span` and not the `a` inside it.

This should work, unless you omitted certain parts of your markup that would otherwise prevent it:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:first-child .combutton a")).click();
```

Comment: can't it be driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".combutton:first-child a")).click(); whihc finds for anchor tag inside first child having class combutton.

Comment: @sandy: No because each `.combutton` is the only child of `div`.

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div span.combutton a[contains(.,'Submit')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div span.combutton[0] a")).click();
```

Comment: Why are you giving an XPath answer to a CSS selector question?

Comment: actually, i'm not sure about cssSelector instruction. And apprently, this guy has tested with xpath on the web browser and don't know about cssSelector syntax. so i give him a answer that he can understand a little bit more ;)